# Equation For a CNOT Gate Matrix, that works on multiple qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, linear-algebra

So Say I have 3 qubits, $\lvert000\rangle$, And I want to apply a Pauli-X Gate to the second qubit.

I know that I can create the matrix that will act on those qubits, using this equation:
$$
X_{2,3} = Id \otimes X \otimes Id
$$
Where Id is a 2x2 identity matrix.

---

How would I do something similar to that with a CNOT Gate? (A General Equation for creating that would be great)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the qubits are adjacent, then it's exactly the same technique: use a tensor product. $CNOT_{2 \rightarrow 3} = I \otimes CNOT$.

If they're not adjacent, you can use a swap gate to make them adjacent, then apply the CNOT, then swap back. Multiply the matrices together to get the full matrix.

---

Alternatively, here's a trick. Imagine that there's a special "control value" $c$ that's not a normal number. The strange thing about $c$ is that the tensor product of any matrix $M$ against $c$ is $c \otimes M = c \cdot I$ instead of $c \cdot M$.

Now declare that a control has the matrix $C = \begin{bmatrix} c & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, and compute:

$
\begin{align}
CNOT_{3 \rightarrow 1}
&= X \otimes I \otimes C
\\
&= X \otimes I \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= X \otimes \begin{bmatrix} I \otimes c&I \otimes 0\\I \otimes 0&I \otimes 1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= X \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c \cdot I & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= X \otimes \begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c&0\\0&c \end{bmatrix} & 0 \\ 0 & \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= X \otimes \begin{bmatrix} c&&&\\&c&&\\&&1&\\&&&1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} X \otimes c&&&\\&X \otimes c&&\\&&X \otimes 1&\\&&&X \otimes 1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} I \cdot c&&&\\&I \cdot c&&\\&&X&\\&&&X \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} c\\&c\\&&c\\&&&c\\&&&&&1\\&&&&1\\&&&&&&&1\\&&&&&&1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$

Once you're done, replace the $c$'s with 1s and voila:

$CNOT_{3 \rightarrow 1}
 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\&1\\&&1\\&&&1\\&&&&0&1\\&&&&1&0\\&&&&&&0&1\\&&&&&&1&0 \end{bmatrix}
$

This trick is [flexible enough that it will work on controls that aren't along the computational basis](http://algorithmicassertions.com/impractical-experiments/2015/05/17/Treating-Controls-like-Values.html) such as the X-axis control $H \cdot C \cdot H$. But there are some gotchas where it breaks.

Comment: To Summerise the generation Equation, would this be correct? (With $G$ being the 2x2 matrix you want to apply, $control$ being the number of the qubit controlling the opperation, $target$ being the number of the qubit you want to apply $G$ to conditionally, and $n$ being the total number of qubits in the register): $$  CG_{control, target, n} = \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\otimes}}
 \begin{cases}
     G & \text{if} \quad i = target\text{;} \\
     C & \text{if} \quad i = control\text{;} \\
     Id & \text{otherwise.} 
 \end{cases}  $$

Comment: Yes, as long as $G$ is a single-qubit operation and we're keeping in mind that this is a non-standard tensor-product that handles the $c$ value special.